# how to "insert into table (col1, col2) values (select max(id) from table2, select id from table3); "?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I am trying to create a many-many relationship between the max(id) in table1 with all the ids in table2, using a lookup table called table1_table2.

Ultimately so that the rows in table1_table2 will be:

```
table1_id, table2_id
30, 1
30, 2
30, 3
...
30, 10000
```

How can I do this?

I have tried

```
insert into insert into table1_table2 (table1_id, table2_id) 
   values (select max(id) from table2, select id from table3);
```

and

```
insert into insert into table1_table2 (table1_id, table2_id) 
   select max(table1_id), table2_id from table1 
      join table1_table2 on table1_table2.table1_id = table1.id 
      outer join table1_table2 on table1_table2.table2_id = table2.id;
```

But neither seem to work

Comment: Can you add in the question where the data are now? In `table2`, `table3` or both ?

Comment: the data are currently in both, I am trying to create a many-many relationship between the max(id) in table1 with all the ids in table2, using a lookup table called table1_table2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like this is what you want:

```
INSERT INTO table1_table2 (table1_id, table2_id) 
    SELECT MAX(table1.id), table2.id FROM table1, table2 GROUP BY table2.id;
```

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks. helpful use of 'group by' to avoid duplicates (even though I did not specify this, it is the primary key, so there would be none).

Answer (score 3):

You have 3 tables, I see. I guess you mean this:

```
insert into table1_table2 (table1_id, table2_id) 
   SELECT
         (select max(id) from table2)            --- or perhaps: from table1 ?
       , id
   FROM table3                                   --- or perhaps: FROM table2 ?
```

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks. you are correct with the 'from table1 and from table2' rather than table2 and table3. Sorry that I changed the question.