# Mysql->autoincrementing related to an other field

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment, ddl

I am stuck on a project design. One of the table has 1-M relation with users table. So it has a foreign key. Same field is also primary key.

Table as follows

Itemid:

- Primarykey
- Autoincrement

Useriditem:

- Primarykey
- Foreign key of id in users table

Itemname:

- Not null

Values:

```
-----------------------------------------
|  **ITEMID** | **USERID** | ITEMNAME   |
-----------------------------------------
| 1           | 1          | fooooooo   |
-----------------------------------------
| 2           | 1          | tinytext   |
-----------------------------------------
| 3           | 1          | MediumText |
-----------------------------------------
| 4           | 2          | LARGEtext  |
-----------------------------------------
| 5           | 2          | HUGETEXT   |
-----------------------------------------
| 6           | 1          | BLOOOOOB   |
-----------------------------------------
| 7           | 3          | 001010101  |
-----------------------------------------
```

This is the result of the current design. What i am wondering is that a way to make auto increment for each user separately.

Something like "Autoincrement item id GROUP BY  user id"

```
-----------------------------------------
|  **ITEMID** | **USERID** | ITEMNAME   |
-----------------------------------------
| 1           | 1          | fooooooo   |
-----------------------------------------
| 2           | 1          | tinytext   |
-----------------------------------------
| 3           | 1          | MediumText |
-----------------------------------------
|   1         | 2          | LARGEtext  |
-----------------------------------------
|   2         | 2          | HUGETEXT   |
-----------------------------------------
| 4           | 1          | BLOOOOOB   |
-----------------------------------------
|      1      | 3          | 001010101  |
-----------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to do this using mysql?

Comment: You have 2 tables that have auto increment primary keys and have 1 to many relationships. I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry i cleared the issue and updated the question. What im trying to do is autoincrementing itemid by userid occurrences.

Comment: You should use a trigger on INSERT on table items

Comment: `CREATE TRIGGER ai_seperatly BEFORE INSERT ON table
FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN
  IF user_id = 'theid'


 SET %maxid = %maxid + 1;
END;
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('theid',%maxid,'foo') `

I managed to write this but trigger needs the user id that will be inserted. Is it possible to insert values to triggers ?? 
@CodeBird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this:

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bd40e/1)

```
CREATE TRIGGER item_id_auto_inc
BEFORE INSERT ON items
FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN
    SET NEW.item_id := (SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(MAX(item_id)) THEN 0 ELSE MAX(item_id) END +1 FROM items WHERE user_id=NEW.user_id);
END
//
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted. dml seems more capable then i thought. Thanks a lot.

Comment: side note: that's DDL, trigger creation is DDL. @user2102266

Comment: What happens if multiple users try to access it concurrently? The max(item_id) may be an issue.

Comment: What do you mean issue caused by multiple users? I posted a answer. Is it safe in your persfective? @Mukus

Comment: that won't happen as each insert will wait for the other. He's thinking if many inserts run simultaneously this would cause the trigger to fail to get the max(id)

Comment: @CodeBird not fail to get the max(id), but get incorrect max(id). What guarantees the wait?

Comment: @user2102266 Have a look at MySQL documentation on LAST_INSERT_ID(). This is still not a safe way to do things but MAX_ID() is not safe at all if you have two inserts statements firing at the same time. At CodeBird please look at comments of the accepted answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837990/last-insert-id-mysql. That's how mysql works?

Comment: @Mukus you are mixing up things. `last_insert_id` depends on mysql open link, so it will get you the last_insert_id that was inserted using your current link. `max` function gets you the max id of the table regardless of the link. That's what they're saying in the post you linked, that actually proves my point, what they're saying is that if an insert arrives to mysql before OP's second insert or before he selects max(id) his max(id) value will change which will be wrong for him but is good in this question because we want the max(itemid) of the table in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what happens when multiple users execute queries but i think i managed to narrow down the algorithm.

[how to "insert into table (col1, col2) values (select max(id) from table2, select id from table3); "?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572295/how-to-insert-into-table-col1-col2-values-select-maxid-from-table2-selec)

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ( 
(SELECT (MAX(itemid)+1)
FROM table
WHERE userid = 'theid') , 'theid' , 'foo1');
```

Can this solve the simultaneous execution by multiple user problem.

Comment: that's the same thing, additionally if you don't test your MAX(itemid) if there is no itemid at all, this will return null, and null + 1 stays null, so all your table itemid will be full of null

Answer (score 0):

The safer way to do this is taking into account that your application can get hit by more than 1 user at any given time

```
START TRANSACTION;
 Insert into table A
 Select Last inserted id from table A using Last_Insert_ID()
 Update table B
COMMIT;
```

At least you are guaranteed to get this last inserted id from table A into table B.